# API to make Video call using Wi-fi/LAN in iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm currently working on how to make a video call to other ipad using Wi-fi or through LAN, can anyone list some API which supports video call functioning? please provide any links or codings regarding how video call works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default way to create video call one iPad to other...

The FaceTime is integrable into the iOS apps using one of the following URL schemas:

- facetime://myfriend
- facetime://myfriend@somewhere.com
- facetime://5558675309

Unfortunately this is an nondocumented way, so according to [this Apple Developer forum post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/629980#629980), Apple rejects apps that uses this FaceTime API. So i think, it is not a feasible feature now.

I'm sure that there is some Video call SDK, e.g. [TokBox](http://tokbox.com/live-video-ios-sdk) or [iDoubs](http://code.google.com/p/idoubs) (open-source option)

One of the most simple way to integrate Skype into your app using the following URL schema, but it's not sure, that it is enough for you.

```
NSString *contact= @"MyDude";
NSURL *skypeURL= [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"skype://%@?call", contact]];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:skypeURL]) {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:skypeURL];
}
```

Good luck!